# using xargs with output piped to awk throws syntax error

Tags: bash, awk, sed, xargs

Team, 
I read many posts but its unclear to me..

I need to understand how to deal with this.. I have xargs doing some evaluation and then am piping to awk but get syntax error

file.log

```
node1,
node2,
node3,
```

failing expression with xargs and awk

```
cat file.log | awk -F ',' '{print $1}' | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --no-headers --field-selector spec.nodeName=$1 | awk "{if ($1 ~ "team-") print $1,$2}"' --
```

passing till here

```
cat file.log | awk -F ',' '{print $1}' | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --no-headers --field-selector spec.nodeName=$1
```

as soon as i add awk part..am not getting it.

output:

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
```

Alternate solution I found is move the awk out of xargs --. so below works. but how can i get the awk inside because I would like to print the $1 that am using in xargs to see correlation with what awk is printing.

```
WORKS

--field-selector spec.nodeName=$1' -- | awk '{if ($1 ~ "team-") print $1,$2}'
```

```
FAILS

--field-selector spec.nodeName=$1 | awk '{if ($1 ~ "team-") print $1,$2}' --
```

Comment: This is just a shell quotation issue. You can use `'\''{if ($1 ~ "team-") print $1,$2}'\''` instead

Comment: does not work. I get > on prompt and no execution. ```| awk '\''{if ($1 ~ "team-") print $1,$2}'\'' --
```

Comment: why is there -2 on my question?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out with the help of "[How do I use awk's single quotes within another single quote phrase?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528238/how-do-i-use-awks-single-quotes-within-another-single-quote-phrase)"

Here is what worked for me. I quoted `awk` in dQuotes and then escaped `$` inside:

```
cat file.log | 
awk -F ',' '{print $1}' | 
xargs -l1 -- sh -c \
   'kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --no-headers \
                     --field-selector spec.nodeName=$1 | 
    awk "{if (\$1 ~ \"team-\") print \$1,\$2}"
    ' --
```